# Getting "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'" error

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error when i run the below code. I didn't find anything wrong with my code. Can anyone help me?

```
data = open('F:\\Chapter 2\\Customer Churn Model.txt','r')
col = data.next().strip().split(',')
no_col = len(data.next().strip().split(','))
print(no_col)strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

File object in Python 3.x does not support next() method. It is supported only in Python 2.x. Here is the link explaining this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_next.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can change this code to the context manager form:

```
with open('F:\\Chapter 2\\Customer Churn Model.txt','r') as data:
    col = data.readline().strip().split(',')
    no_col = len(data.readline().strip().split(','))
    print(no_col)
```

Your error is caused by lacking of the `next` method for an _io.TextIOWrapper object instntiated by `open` built-in. Instead of it you should use `readline` to read a single line from file. This metdod will read file line by line, but beware of errors if there's not enough lines.

P.S. `data = open('F:\\Chapter 2\\Customer Churn Model.txt','r')` string is correct too, but context manager is more pythonic and safer style.

About python3 `next`:  there's no `next` method in python3, but `__next__` which is called by built-in `next()` function, if it's defined.

Example:

```
generator = (i for i in range(10))
next(generator)

Out:
0
```

But it is not a good code, better to use `for` keyword iterate. Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next